# ViewController's subview's IBOutlets nil in viewDidLoad from Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a `UIViewController` that gets instantiated from a Storyboard.
In this view controller lays a `MyView` that is actually just a `UIView` from a Xib file.

In the view controller, I set my view as being a class of `MyView` and link it to an `IBOutlet` in my view controller class.

`MyView` contains a `UILabel`.

When in the view controller, in `viewDidLoad` I try to set `myView.myLabel.text = "test"` I get a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`, `myLabel` is nil.

Can't figure out what's wrong.

Even in `awakeFromNib()` and in `required init?(coder)` my outlet is nil.

Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: is your myView is nil also?

Comment: No it's not nil

Comment: I have updated answer check that if it is working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Double check to make sure your link between storyboard and code is ok. I had this once when broke the connection and all I had to do was reconnect it.

[image]

Comment: I removed all the links and recreated them again, it's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

See if you are using `CustomViewClass` in xib i would like to tell you first declare property as `@IBOutlet var viewObject: CustomViewClass!` in your `Vc.swift` & then give outlet opposite in storyboard & then inner subviews outlet declare in the `CustomViewClass.swift`

Now you are feel free to access in the your `Vc.swift` that innersubviews outlets of your `CustomViewClass` like

```
viewObject.myLabel.text = "test"
```

Don't forget to give `Custom Class` from identity inspector  for **file's owner** `Vc` & your view `CustomViewClass`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Still if you have any doubt feel free to ask in comment.

Comment: I did all of that but I still get the problem

Comment: I would like to repeat are sure giving `MyView` class to your ParentView of your label ?

Comment: Check your issue step by step in your swift project & be note my outlet is in Vc.h i have worked  long time ago in obj-c. :D

Comment: I already told you it is not possible to set outlet from storyboard to Your Vc. You have to write outlet manually  & then you have to connect it in the storyboard.